# failed install of ghost.py python module in windows with ipython

Tags: python, installation, ipython

I need help getting ghost.py to be recognised by ipython notebook which i run from c/python27/scripts

I also installed pyQt4 via a binary from chris gohlke but which also isn't being recognised by my ipython installation under windows.

i downloaded zip from github extracted to a folder inside c/python27/scripts directory and installed it via command prompt

python install setup.py

but when I import ghost and try and use it my Ipython it is not recognised.

**update: pyQt4 is not being recognised even though it's installed under c/python27/lib/site-pacakges, and the path is in the variable name**

Comment: How did you install IPython? It might be installed in a different copy of Python on your system.

Comment: I installed it via the exe I downloaded? how can I tell if it's a different instance of python, I have 2.7 and 3.3 I believe. How do I know which instance?

Comment: how do you see a list of installed libraries? and the paths they are installed to? Kind of like a windows/ add remove programs dialogue box but for python instances and libraries?

Comment: In IPython, do `import sys; sys.__version__` to see which version of Python IPython is running on, and `import IPython; IPython` to see where it's installed. To see all installed modules, you can try doing `help('modules')`, but it doesn't work very reliably.

Comment: so python has no way of determining what third party libraries are installed?

Comment: When I run those commands it says "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f6b6e4aff084> in <module>()
----> 1 import sys; sys.__version__
      2 import IPython; IPython

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'"

Comment: from import ipython I get "Out[4]:

<module 'IPython' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\__init__.pyc'>"

Comment: Sorry, change `__version__` to `version`. It does look like IPython is installed under Python 2.7. You said you installed ghost via `python setup.py install` - what do you get if you do `python --version` at a Windows command prompt?

Comment: When I run sys.version I get " 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
 ", and when I run it in command prompt I get 2.7

Comment: I thought maybe the modules might be named something else, like beautifulsoup for me is from bs4, not import beautifulsoup. Maybe pyqt4 is different like p4 or someting.